# How to sort Google chat's contacts by last contacted?

Tags: google-talk

How can I sort Google Talk's contacts that are shown on the bottom left of Gmail by last contacted? Right now I have it sorted alphabetically, it seems, which is not that useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option in Google Talk. There might be a 3rd-party Google Talk client that allows that kind of sorting but I'm unaware of it. This functionality requires storing conversation logs or access to logs saved in GMail, which are optional.